# How I deserialize Avro from Kafka with embedded schema

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, avro

I recieve binary Avro files from a Kafka topic and I must deserialize them. In the message received by Kafka, I can see a schema at the start of every message. I know it's a better practice to not embed the schema and separate it from the actual Avro file, but I don't have control over the producer and I can't change that.

My code runs on top of Apache Storm. First I create a reader:

```
mDatumReader = new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>();
```

And later I try to deserialize the message without declaring schema:

```
Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(messageBytes, null);
GenericRecord payload = mDatumReader.read(null, decoder);
```

But then I get an error when a message arrives:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: writer cannot be null!
at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.resolve(ResolvingDecoder.java:77) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.<init>(ResolvingDecoder.java:46) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.avro.io.DecoderFactory.resolvingDecoder(DecoderFactory.java:307) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.getResolver(GenericDatumReader.java:122) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:137) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
```

All the answers I've seen are about using other formats, changing the messages delivered to Kafka or something else. I don't have control over those things.

My question is, given a message in `bytes[]` with embedded schema inside binary message, how to deserialize that Avro file without declaring schema so I can read it.

Answer (score 2):

With the DatumReader/Writer, there is no such thing like an embedded schema. Had been my misunderstanding when looking at Avro & Kafka the first time as well. But the source code of the Avro Serializer clearly shows there is no schema embedded when using the GenericDatumWriter.

It is the Data**File**Writer who does write a schema at the beginning of the file and then adds GenericRecords using the GenericDatumWriter.

Since you said there is a schema at the beginning, I assume you can read it, turn it into a Schema object and then pass that into the GenericDatumReader(schema) constructor.
Would be interesting to know how the message is serialized. Maybe the DataFileWriter is used to write into a byte[] instead of an actual file, then you could use the DataFileReader to deserialize the data?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add Maven Dependancy

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
       <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>1.9.1</version>
       <type>maven-plugin</type>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Create a file like below

   ```
    {"namespace": "tachyonis.space",
      "type": "record",
      "name": "Avro",
      "fields": [
         {"name": "Id", "type": "string"},
       ]
     }
   ```
3. Save above as Avro.avsc in src/main/resources.
4. In Eclipse or any IDE Run > Maven generate sources which create Avro.java to package folder [namespace] tachyonis.space

   ```
   props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
   props.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG);
   props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
   props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
   props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, true); 
   KafkaConsumer<String, Avro> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
   ```
5. The consumer/producer has to run in the same machine.  Otherwise you need to configure hosts file in Windows/Linux and change all components configurations properties from localhost to map to the actual IP address for broadcast to the producers/consumers.  Otherwise you get errors like network connection issues

   ```
   Connection to node -3 (/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem with spring boot.

A different system sends messages with embedded schema as part of the payload:

```
Objavro.schema#{"type":"record","name":"CONTACTS","namespace":"my.avros","fields":[{"name":"EXTERNAL_CONTACT_ID","type":"string"},{"name":"EXTERNAL_SYSTEM","type":"string"},{"name":"CONTACT_ID","type":["null","int"]},{"name":"CREATE_TIMESTAMP","type":"string"},{"name":"UPDATE_TIMESTAMP","type":"string"}],"version":"1"}####F#[####)Ml1068GSIS##&2020-06-26T08:33:28&2021-06-25T10:47:43####F# [####)M
```

This is how I managed to deserialize the data via wrapping the byte array into a FileReader:

First: we shared our AVRO schemas across the systems:

```json
{ 
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "my.avro",
  "name": "CONTACTS",
  "version": "1",
  "fields": 
  [
    {
      "name": "EXTERNAL_CONTACT_ID",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "EXTERNAL_SYSTEM",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "CONTACT_ID",
      "type": ["null", "int"]
    },
    {
      "name": "CREATE_TIMESTAMP",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "UPDATE_TIMESTAMP",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

then we generate source code via the avro-maven-plugin

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
    <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>schema</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/avro/</sourceDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/avro</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then, within our KafkaListener we wrap our payload into a `DataFileReader`:

```java
import org.apache.avro.file.DataFileReader;
import org.apache.avro.file.SeekableByteArrayInput;
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader;

//...

  public void deSerializeAvroBinary(byte[] data) throws IOException {
    DatumReader<CONTACTS> datumReader =
        new SpecificDatumReader<>(CONTACTS.getClassSchema());

    CONTACTS output;

    try (DataFileReader<CONTACTS> dataFileReader = new DataFileReader(
        new SeekableByteArrayInput(data), datumReader)) {
      while (dataFileReader.hasNext()) {
        output = dataFileReader.next();
        // do whatever you want with the data
        log.info(output.toString());
      }
    }
  }
```

**Side note:**

Within our application properties, we configured our Kafka consumer in the following way:

```yaml
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9093
    security:
      protocol: "SSL"
    consumer:
      group-id: "my_testgroupid"
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
      ssl:
        key-store-location: file:/my-consumer-cert.p12
        key-store-password: *************
        trust-store-location: file:/truststore.p12
        trust-store-password: *************
```